# how do play audio file repetitively in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

how do play audio file repetitively in windows phone 7. I want to play the audio file in background of the application repetitively when app is running.

```
Uri mediaUri = new Uri("Kalimba.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

PlayNewFile(mediaUri);

private void PlayNewFile(Uri mediaUri)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        if (null != mediaUri && null != Switch_mediaElement) 
        {
            Switch_mediaElement.Stop();
            Switch_mediaElement.Source = mediaUri;
            Switch_mediaElement.Volume = 100;
            Switch_mediaElement.IsMuted = false;

            Switch_mediaElement.Play();

        }
    }
```

It plays the file only once when application launched.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741866.aspx) MSDN article on how to repeat media playback.

Hope this helps.